# Difference between disposable address, integrated address and subaddress?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

I've been searching the web for a while, but I'm still not quite clear what roles do they play.

Some of my questions are:

1. Has disposable address been removed from the wallet, since I can't find how to generate one in monero-wallet-cli's help message? (wallet version Helium Hydra v0.11.0.0).
2. Since integrated address combines payment id and standard address in an encrypted way, why do we still need subaddress?

I would be grateful if someone could clear up my confusion.

*English is not my first language, please edit for clarity, then remove this comment.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Has disposable address been removed from the wallet, since I can't find how to generate one in monero-wallet-cli's help message? (wallet version Helium Hydra v0.11.0.0).

Disposable address was never added to the official Monero wallet. It was originally proposed in [PR-1345](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/1345) which inspired an improved version called subaddress in [PR-1753](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/1753). Disposable address was ultimately dropped in the final version [PR-2056](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/2056) due to the severe limitation that the address reuse will cause privacy leak.

> 2. Since integrated address combines payment id and standard address in an encrypted way, why do we still need subaddress?

The payment ID embedded inside the integrated address is *NOT* encrypted. The payment ID gets encrypted when the sender constructs the transaction and the transaction is recorded on the blockchain, which can be decrypted only by the receiver.

The purpose of subaddress was to hide the fact from the sender (or anyone other than the receiver, for that matter) that multiple seemingly unrelated addresses actually belong to the same receiver. The only traditional way to achieve this goal was to simply generate multiple wallets (i.e. multiple seeds), which was not only tedious but also highly inefficient.