# Can someone send monero to my subaddress that starts with "8"?

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-rpc, address, sub-address

After I got my wallet onto mainnet, I get an address **starts with "8"** (normal monero address starts with "4"), and it's a subaddress with a costom label. **Can someone send funds to that address?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a subaddress is a valid public address and can be used the same as a "normal" account address.

[Here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6892/difference-between-disposable-address-integrated-address-and-subaddress) and [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3673/what-is-a-sub-address) are more information on subaddresses.